# Using a string as a parameter in requirejs text plugin

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I wanted to use a string within require and load a handlebar template file. But i always get

> "Invalid require call : notloaded",'Module name "'+i+'" has not been loaded yet for context:"

---

```
define(function( require) {

  var getTemplateFile = function(templateName) {
     return require(['text!../html/templates/header.tpl']);   /* This works */
  }

});


//String Concatenated
define(function( require) {

  var getTemplateFile = function(templateName) {
     return require(['text!../html/templates/'+templateName+'.tpl']);   /* Does not work */
  }

});
```

I followed workaround given here ( [RequireJS text plugin and variable concatenated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193466/requirejs-text-plugin-and-variable-concatenated-string) ) but still i got the same error.
Any help in getting this working.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the require function. See [here for the spec](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/require.md). You'll want to use `require(String)` (along with the array version) or just `require(Array, Function)` depending on what exactly you want to achieve. The answer you linked to uses the array variation.